# VBA (Excel): Filter array on multiple criteria and find the lowest value

Tags: excel, vba, search, criteria

I have a two tables with data. The first one contains data wither a higher level of details as it contains one more dimension. I need a method to find the lowest value in Table1 Column D, where Criteria1 and Criteria2 matches the corresponding value in Column A and Column B.

For example, for Criteria1 = A and Criteria2 = F, both row 2 and row 3 in Table1 maches. The lowest value (12) in Column D is on row 3. The matching value (12 in this case) should be inserted into a new column in Table2.

**Table1**

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D (Value)
A              F           X         13
A              F           Y         12
B              F           Y         15
B              G           Z         17
B              G           X         12,5
```

**Table2**

```
Criteria1   Criteria2
A              F
B              F
B              G
```

**Table2 with inserted lowest value**

```
Criteria1   Criteria2   Lowest Value (new column)
A              F            12
B              F            15
B              G            12,5
```

My assumption is that this could either be done through a combination of INDEX and MATCH, or through advanced filter. The table is 7000 rows, so not huge. However, I need support how to solve this as it is looks like a two step method is required.

Answer (score -1):

pseudo code for a Function that looks for the minimum value in column C corresponding to column A and B passed criteria.

```
Function GetMinValue(criteriumA as String, criteriumB As String) As Long

    With Table1Range 'haeders row included
        .Autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= criteriumA 
        .Autofilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= criteriumB
        If (condition to check for any filtered Cells) Then GetMinValue=WorksheetFunction.Min(.Columns(4).SpecialCells(onlyVisibleCells))
        removeAutofilter
    End With

End Sub
```

you get plenty of help both in SO and in the web for both `Autofilter ()` and `SpecialCells()` methods of `Range` object

Comment: Would the brave downvoter ever care to explain the reason of his vote and both have me possibly enhance my answer and let other people learn from his thinking?